# How do I sort a nested list using two list elements in R?

Tags: r, sorting, nested-lists

I have a nested list of n elements, each element being itself a list of 4 different values. The values vary but are comparable between elements.

I need to sort the list first by the value of 'm.group', and then by the value 'att'. 'm.group' is an integer of, say, 1:3, and each element in the list is assigned a value of 1:3 (though the total number will vary). Within each numbered group, I need to arrange the members by descending order of 'att', which can be any value between 0 and 2.

I can arrange the list in ascending or descending values of either 'm.group' or 'att' using

`function(a, field) a[order(sapply(a, "[[", i = field),decreasing = T)]`

but I can't work out how to combine the two.

Each element looks like this.

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`ind`
[1] 1

[[1]]$m.group
[1] 3

[[1]]$offspring
[1] 0

[[1]]$att
[1] 0.07626772
```

The values 'offspring' and 'ind' are not important at this stage.

To simplify, I need an output that looks something like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$m.group
[1] 1

[[1]]$att
[1] 1.49352456


[[2]]
[[2]]$m.group
[1] 1

[[2]]$att
[1] 1.23452221


[[3]]
[[3]]$m.group
[1] 1

[[3]]$att
[1] 0.07626772


[[4]]
[[4]]$m.group
[1] 2

[[4]]$att
[1] 1.51852546

[[5]]
[[5]]$m.group
[1] 2

[[5]]$att
[1] 1.35648527
```

etc.

EDIT

You can generate a similar list with the following loop:

```
example <-vector(mode="list", length = 40)

loop.nb<-1
j<-1
for(j in 1:40){

  example[[loop.nb]]$m.group <-sample((round(80/(10*2))),1)

  example[[loop.nb]]$att <- runif(1, min=0, max=1.7)

  loop.nb <-loop.nb+1

}
```

Hope this is clear!

Thanks in advance for your help,

Andy

Comment: It would be better to share some sample data.

Comment: It would! The data are simulated, I've included an example loop above to generate your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by using the `list.sort` function of the `rlist` package:

```
rlist::list.sort(example, m.group, (att))
```

The parentheses enclosing `att` mean you want the descending order.